# Why does calling `fn.length` in JavaScript return the number of named arguments `fn` has?

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain why calling `fn.length` in JavaScript return the number of named arguments `fn` has?

```
> function fn () { }
> x.length
0

> function fn (a) { }
> x.length
1

> function fn (a,b,c) { }
> x.length
3
```

Very strange behavior. I'm curious to learn why that is.

Comment: Surely it would have been quicker to just Google [function.length javascript](https://www.google.com.au/#q=function.length+javascript) yourself, rather than post a question here.

Comment: I think the question is more on the `why` part, he already figured what it is. Unfortunately without the original authors of the ecmascript specification we'll probably never know as there is no reasoning given in [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%201st%20edition,%20June%201997.pdf) under § 15.

Comment: to be pedantic, it reflects the number of "formal parameters", _arguments_ are not set until run-time... It can be misleading, ex: [].map.length is 1, even though it works best with 2 args...

Comment: @dandavis—to be even more pedantic, it's a hint as to the number of arguments typically used. Functions created from expressions or declarations use the number of formal parameters for convenience. Built–ins have defined lengths of the number of arguments typically used (e.g. *pop* has a length of 0, *push* has a length of 1), *map* is typically called with one argument, the second is optional (I don't think it's common to supply a *thisArg* parameter).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length):

> The length property specifies the number of arguments expected by the
>   function.

From [Microsoft's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4cz6db7d(v=vs.94).aspx):

> Gets the number of arguments defined for a function.

From [ECMAScript 2015 specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-function-instances-length):

> The value of the length property is an integer that indicates the
>   typical number of arguments expected by the function.

Comment: Only the last reference has any authority, the link seems broken. Try [*http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-function-instances-length*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-function-instances-length).